# render twitter-bootstrap search-form ad get data from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Cheers,I need to render partial view with simple bootstrap search-form on my app's home page by clicking the button. So, how to do this correctly? And how get query from search-form?
I'm newbie in Rails and AJAX and I'm stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a loot at [Search, Sort, Paginate with Ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) screencast.